# DRY mocha async tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Using mocha I often need to do something like the following in my acceptance tests:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  Factory.createMany('artifact', 2, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    expected = result;

    done();
  });
});
```

It would be nice to DRY it up a bit to get rid of the allways repeading error handling. One idea I came up with is:

```
function failOrRun(done, fn) {
  return function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }

    return fn(result);
  };
}

Factory.createMany('artifact', 2, failOrRun(done, function(result) {
  expected = result;
  done();
}));
```

But this is also not really  readable. It would be nice if you can give me some hints for my refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate issues:

1. code repetition in unit tests.
2. code readability in unit tests.

Regarding the first point, DRY is a useful principle, but do not overestimate his importance when writing Unit Tests. Readability and maintainability are crucial, IMO, and I would trade just a bit of redundancy for a tangible improvement in readability.

The second point is partially opinion based, but I would say: study and learn how to use Promises. It's not that Promises are always safe (you have to remember to always return a Promise inside a `then` and call `fail` to catch runtime errors), but they are WAY easier to read.

You can use the ES6 implementation or a library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) to leverage a robust Promise implementation.

Good luck.